# ansible - FAILED => module whoami not found in configured module paths

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible. I am trying to run simple command however I am getting this error
**FAILED => module whoami not found in configured module paths** after I key in the password. I would appreciate if somebody could  help me to fix this.

Raj

Comment: Do you have "whoami:" somewhere in in your playbook? It seems like your playbook is not in order, please post it.

Comment: whoami is not one of the [stock ansible modules](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_all_modules.html).  Did you obtain it from somewhere else?  If so, where? It's possible it's not installed properly.

Comment: I am not using playbook. I am running on command line  ansible all -m "whoami"

Answer (score 1):

There is no such module called whoami. Here is the [list of all modules](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_all_modules.html)

Your question is very unclear. What is your intent? What have you tried so far? Where is the data (console logs/commands/steps to reproduce) for us to help you?

Assuming you want to run whoami shell command on all machines, use this :

```
ansible all -m shell -a 'whoami' -vvv
```

Check the stdout property in the returned JSON for seeing what each machine returned.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. What i have done so far? I have installed the ansible on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4. I configured the ansible.cfg and then I am trying to run ad-hic command. My host file contains three servers. That's it.  I ran the "ansible all -m shell -a 'whoami' -vvv" , and i was able to move forward and not getting the module not found error but also not getting the output of the command. I am getting the 3 different error now. FAILED => failed to open a SFTP connection FAILED >> {
    "failed": true,
     "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python:  not found\n",

Comment: intentionally, I have not pasted the host name

Comment: My config file has the following under [ssh_connection]
remote_port = 2022
scp_if_ssh = True

Comment: Hey, It seems to me that i have problem in the host list itself. Earlier I had list of AIX server. I removed those server from the hosts file and put three Linux server. and it seems to me that i am getting the output. I am not very clear on one thing which is related to python installation on target hosts. Do I need to have python installed on all the Linux / Aix target hosts?

Comment: You need python 2.4+ on all target nodes. [Check the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements) Ansible looks for remote python  on /usr/bin/python (which can be configured to different path using a host level variable if required).

Comment: Python2 is also easy to install from sources, or from internet on target machines.

Comment: I installed the python on the target nodes. I ran the above command with two server listed in the hosts file. on one server it is running successfully and second it is failing FAILED => failed to open a SFTP connection (EOF during negotiation) any idea?

Comment: Try setting `scp_if_ssh=True` in your ansible.cfg [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#scp-if-ssh)